# JavaScript not working on @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: javascript, html, css, razorengine

When textbox is empty checkbox disabled but when texbox filled removed attribute
as shown in code:
this is work on checkbox but not in razor view engine please anyone help me

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrganizationName, new { @class = "enableSubmitOnChange" }) 
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ShowOnReport, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

JavaScript is

```
   $('input.enableSubmitOnChange').change(function(){
        if($(this).val()!="")
            $(this).parents('form').find('input:checkbox').attr('disabled','');
        else
            $(this).parents('form').find('input:checkbox').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
```

Comment: In your javascript, you are not doing anything with the checkbox, looks like you are enabling and disabling the submit buttons. Not sure what is your expectation. Can you please provide some more details.

Comment: sorry it was checkbox i update my code

Comment: but still it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove disable attribute. Setting it to an empty string still means it is disabled.

```
$(this).parents('form').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');
```